# Update a OneNote page using Graph API

Tags: c#, uwp, microsoft-graph-api, onenote, onenote-api

I am trying to update a OneNote page using the `PATCH` request through the Microsoft Graph API. I keep getting `Error 19999` which according to this https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/office365/howto/onenote-error-codes means "Unknown Error"

```
var pageId = settings.DefaultPage;
string requestUrl = $"https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/onenote/pages/{pageId}/content";
string body = @"{ 
{
'target':'body',
'action':'append',
'position':'after',
'content':'<div> added new </div>'}}";
var content = new StringContent(body, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
HttpRequestMessage req = new HttpRequestMessage()
{
    Method = new HttpMethod("PATCH"),
    Content = content,
    RequestUri = new Uri(requestUrl)
};
HttpClient client = new HttpClient()
{
    BaseAddress = new Uri(requestUrl),
};
client.DefaultRequestHeaders.TryAddWithoutValidation("authorization", "Bearer " + settings.MsaAccessCode);
HttpResponseMessage response = await client.SendAsync(req);
```

I can verify that the Authorization Code is valid (as I am able to do other actions like creating a new page) and has the necessary scopes to update a page. Can anyone help me with identifying the problem here?

Comment: The url should look like this : h t t p s ://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/$metadata#users('16f5a7b6-5a15-4568-aa5a-31bb117e9967')/onenote/pages..The code doesn't recognize "me"

Comment: Can you point me to your source? I got that url from here https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/v1.0/api/page_update

Comment: For your request, can you share the response you see from the API (e.g. all the headers that are returned, including date and X-correlationID?). This will help diagnose the issue.

Comment: "me" needs to be replaced with a valid user.

Comment: The user needs to be mentioned explicitly only when the app calls "Microsoft Graph with their own identity" https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/concepts/auth_v2_service

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your JSON is invalid. Here is what I believe you want.

```
[{
    "target": "body",
    "action": "append",
    "position": "after",
    "content": "<div> added new </div>"
}]
```